# Finding the points where a complex function is real-valued

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math

I have defined the following complex system:

```
syms x 
sys(x) = ((10+1.*i.*x))/(20+(5.*i.*x)+((10.*i.*x).^2))+((1.*i.*x).^3); 
ImaginaryPart = imag(sys)
```

MATLAB returned the following results:

```
ImaginaryPart(x) =

- real(x^3) + imag((10 + x*1i)/(- 100*x^2 + x*5i + 20))


RealPart(x) =

- real(x^3) + imag((10 + x*1i)/(- 100*x^2 + x*5i + 20))
```

Now for which value of `x` will `ImaginaryPart(x)` be `0`?
(i.e. `ImaginaryPart(x)= 0`)?

Comment: Look at `help solve`. Also, I edited your title (among other things), you're free to change it if it's against your liking (but I'm pretty sure this is what you meant).

Comment: In which sense is this a programming question rather than a mathematical one? Would [Mathematics Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) be a better place to ask?

Comment: @njuffa this is a programming question in the sense that MATLAB has built-in solvers to solve exactly these kind of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@AndrasDeak commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242858/finding-the-points-where-a-complex-function-is-real-valued#comment58199813_35242858), [`solve`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) will do the trick for you:

```
S = solve(ImaginaryPart(x)== 0,x);
```